# Synaptik error “no touchpad found” at startup on DELL desktop

Tags: 13.10

I inadvertently clicked on the "synaptiks" (Touchpad management) menu in Kubuntu 13.10 without owning a touchpad with my desktop.  Now every time I boot up I get the Synaptiks error message “no touchpad found”, how do I get rid of this?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

On the bar at the bottom of the screen. On the right hand side is a small arrow which if clicked 
will display hidden icon. Richt click on the one that says synaptiks and select quit. Synaptiks will not load next time and the error message will disapear.